# Calculating Integral by switching order example

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I came across this:

Calculate the following Integral by switching the order of integration.

$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{2y}^{2} e^{-x^2} \,dxdy$

I quite understood the objective of the exercise, showing that by switching the order of integration I can integrate a function that at first glance looks ""impossible"" to do because of the integral of $e^{-x^2}$. But, for some reason I am getting confused when resolving it. Solution( $\frac{1}{4}(1-e^{-4})$)

Comment: Hint: draw the region of integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region for integral is triangular region between $y = 0, x = 2y, x = 2$.

[image]

So if you integrate wrt $dy$ first and then $dx$, the bounds become,

$0 \leq y \leq \frac{x}{2}$ and $0 \leq x \leq 2$. Can you see how sketching of the region would have helped?

I will leave for you to evaluate the integral which is now straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, at first I though this would be more analitycal,rather than thinking it geometrically. Guess I made confusion when my teacher said the order of integral doesn't matter. But it only works,for the most part, for definite integrals right?

Comment: Yes you are right. This will work only for definite integrals in specific regions. In this region, change of order does make the integral straightforward to evaluate. It may not always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need to look at the shape the bounds give you. Graphing is essential. here the inner bounds go from $x=2y$  to $x=2$  This means we are sweeping from left to right from the line $y=\frac 1 2 x$ to the line $x=2$.  Then we are going from the y values $0$ to $1$.  This creates a triangular region,  bounded by $y=0,  x=2$ and $y=\frac 1 2 x$

Now we need to re-write the problem where we are doing up to down first instead of left to right,  now y as functions of x.   So your inner bounds in x will be $y=0$  and $y=\frac 1 2 x$  and your outer x bounds are $0$ and $2$.   From that you should be able to finish.

Answer (score 0):

First, make the variable changes $ u=\frac12 x$ and $v=y$ to integrate over half of a unit square

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{2y}^{2} e^{-x^2} \,dxdy
= 2 \int_{0}^{1} \int_{v}^{1} e^{-4u^2} \,dudv
$$
Then, switch the integration order as follows

$$I= 2 \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{u} e^{-4u^2} \,dv du= 2 \int_{0}^{1} u e^{-4u^2} du= \frac14(1-e^{-4})
$$